# Is there a GUI or context menu for Windows Explorer for PsFile?

Tags: windows-explorer, sysinternals

[PsFile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897552.aspx) is a great tool for closing network files that have been held open for some reason on another machine.  This happens a lot with Office files, often because the user just left the file open and then left for the day.  It is kind of a pain to have to use the command line to do this, and I have been unable to find a GUI for it.  There are plenty of GUIs for *deleting* locked files (FileASSASSIN, LockHunter, etc.), but that is not what I am looking for; I just want to release the file for writing, basically.

Ideally, I would like to be able to right-click the file in Windows Explorer and select Release, and viola! the file is released.

Comment: You could always create a context menu item to run a program or whatever you specify. To add a context item to right clicking head here: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers` Then add a new key which will be what's see in the context menu, then a new entry called `command` then edit the default key for `command` and include the full path to your program.

Answer (score 1):

I did some googling and came across the following, which should allow you to get hooks into whatever command you want:http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/

I believe in the command that you can use the %1 for the file name. When you do this, you just need to prepend the command to release the file then you should be good.